# Serving ads in adsense while having a adwords account

Tags: google-adsense

I have created a adwords account. I deposited Rs 4000 and serving ads successfully. Now when i apply for adsense account for my same website the account is rejected saying "Site does not comply with Google policies".

Where as my website is a simple web programming blog and does not contain any illegal content.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

URL for reference: 2lessons.info

Answer (score 2):

There is no relation between Google adwords and Adsense; Google Adsense will approve your website if it comply Google AdSense policies.

You must receive rejection email from Google right? kindly ask them for providing details about policy violation of your blog and do recommended changes.